# Why doesn't list.index() raise a ValueError when value isn't found?

Tags: python-3.x

I made a function that returns a list of indices for a given item, not just the first one. However, it doesn't throw `ValueError exception` when the item is not found, it returns an empty list.

What am I doing wrong? When I do this in the interpreter, it raises the exception like it should.

```
def find_items(array, item):
    ''' searches a list or tuple and returns
    a list of indices for a given item '''
    indices = []
    position = 0
    for _ in range(array.count(item)):
        indices.append(array.index(item, position))
        position = indices[-1] + 1
    return indices              

numbers = [42, 1, 2, 3, 42, 42, 42, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 42]
found_indices = find_items(numbers, 1000)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array.count(item)` returns the number of times item appeared in the list.

eg:  `array.count(42)` will return **5** for your input

In your case 1000 has appeared 0 times so your code becomes:

```
for _ in range(0):
```

In short your for loop doesn't run so it returns the empty list as it is initialized.